# The proper AWS managed policy to attach an IAM Role to execute Lambda Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

So, I have created a role via AWS IAM service. Initially, it only has the AWS managed policy `AWSAppSyncPushToCloudWatchLogs`.

Now I want to make this role capable of **executing Lambda functions** and **nothing more** (You know, a good security structure should not permit a bit more from what is needed).

To do that which AWS managed policy(-ies) should I attach to the IAM Role?

PS: The role will be used by AWS AppSync, if this information is crucial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach managed policy, **AWSLambdaRole**. This grants permissions for your role to invoke any Lambda function.

policy statement

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html#access-policy-examples-aws-managed for more details.

Comment: `AWSLambdaRole` looks like the appropriate one. Thanks. Going to accept your answer once it is edited into a more readable format, though :)